# Difference between topological and geometric configurations

Tags: general-topology, geometry, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

If we have a configuration of, say $n$ points in a plane with lines, what is the distinction between this configuration being geometric versus topological?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we have a geometric line, we mean a line in the usual sense, that is a line that is straight.

In the topological sense, we extend this to include pseudolines, that is curves that share certain topological properties with lines.